# How to scale and show next/previous items in a Collection View?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm working on a collection view that should look like this:

[image]

The scroll view works but I want to make my collection view peak the next item like in the screenshot, and when scrolling it scales the normal size of course.

I couldn't manage to do that with only enabling paging (of course).

Thank you all for any help!

Edit:
This kinda helps what I want to achieve, but it still lacks scaling and does not work near good while scrolling.

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return -100
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to tweak the behaviour of item sizing inside `UICollectionView` you should subclass `UICollectionViewLayout` or `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` class and add the sizing behaviour inside `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)`.

The following examples expects that `UICollectionView` aspect ratio is 1:0.7 and `UICollectionViewCell` ratio is 3:4. Layout is subclassed from `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` class. Below code then down scales the item based on the distance from the centre.

```swift
override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    guard let collectionView = self.collectionView else { return nil }

    // Get the array of layout attributes from the superclass, which will be the starting point for modification.
    let attributesArray = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)?.map { $0.copy() as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes }

    // Calculate the center of the visible rect to use as a reference point for scaling.
    let center = collectionView.contentOffset.x + (collectionView.bounds.width / 2.0)

    // Iterate over the layout attributes array and adjust the attributes of cells within the visible rect.
    attributesArray?.forEach { attributes in
        // Ensure we're only adjusting attributes for cells that are visible.
        if attributes.frame.intersects(rect) {
            // Determine how far the cell's center is from the center of the visible rect.
            let distanceFromCenter = abs(center - attributes.center.x)
            // Define the point at which cells no longer scale.
            let maxDistance = (collectionView.bounds.width / 2) + (attributes.size.width / 2)
            // Normalize the distance to a factor between 0 and 1.
            let normalizedDistance = min(distanceFromCenter / maxDistance, 1)
            // Define the minimum scale factor (e.g., no cell will be smaller than 70% of its original size).
            let minimumScaleFactor: CGFloat = 0.7
            // Calculate the scale factor based on the cell's distance from the center.
            let scaleFactor = 1 - (1 - minimumScaleFactor) * normalizedDistance
            // Apply a 3D scale transform to the cell's attributes.
            attributes.transform3D = CATransform3DMakeScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, 1)
            // Ensure that cells closer to the center appear above others.
            attributes.zIndex = Int(scaleFactor * 10)
        }
    }

    return attributesArray
}

override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
    // Invalidate the layout on bounds changes to recalculate scaling for new cell positions.
    return true
}
```

This will make effect as shown on the following image, but without paging. For getting paging to work you should also override `targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset:withScrollingVelocity:)` method on the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` subclass and apply appropriate  logic to it.
[image: Scaled item UICollectionView]

Answer (score 0):

You can of course do this with collectionView or scrollview, however I recommend using some well made external library for this. Try looking at [this Library](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) You can also Install it with CocoaPods , looke here: [cocoapods link](https://cocoapods.org/pods/iCarousel)
I think it will serve you well.

If you want to do this entirely by yourself try taking advantage of this `UICollectionViewDelegate` function with implementing `CGAffineTransform` scaling :

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay willDisplayCell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt forItemAtIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = willDisplayCell as? YourCell else { return }
    cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, y: 2)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I don't want to use a pod for this and want to create it myself if I can find any documentation.

Comment: @OğuzhanVarsak I edidted my earlier response with some code that might help you . It is based on my colleague previous solution for this . He once did the functionality by himself, but later on switched to using library for some reason..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do all in one at go, please go Ui collection view delegate.function with implementing CGAFFineTransform scaling.

Comment: Is there some sample code you could share?

Comment: Yes, sample code would be super helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ICarousel` pod for doing this. You can also set another Carousel types.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33464080)

Comment: I am aware of this pod, but looking to ways to implement it natively without pods.